# Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript

I currently have this line in a javascript function that posts a message to channel 1 with realtime.co

```
xRTML.ConnectionManager.sendMessage({connections: ['myConnection'], channel: '1',
                                    content:xrtmlMessage});
```

This works fine.
My problem is using a variable, let's say 'x', instead of explicitly stating  - channel: '1'.
Essentially I want to be able to post to different channels by writing - ... channel: x, ...
But writing this gives the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'indexOf'
'x' is already declared as x=1;
So I tried declaring y='1'; (with single marks instead of none) and writing channel: y - and this works. So I tried building this as a string (mark 1 mark)

```
y = "'" + x + "'";
```

This gives the error that the channel has invalid characters, so no double quotation marks or escaping the single mark with a backslash either, tried that. I also tried parseInt(x); to ensure x was an integer, to no avail.
Has anyone got any other suggestions or even tried doing the same thing with xRTML?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a bit of additional information to the accepted answer - The reason your solution with "y" doesn't work is that you're setting y to a string consisting of three characters: 'x' (a single quote, an x, then another single quote). To get the effect from that that you were going for, you'd have to use eval(), which is major bad mojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried toString()?

```
xRTML.ConnectionManager.sendMessage({connections: ['myConnection'], channel: x.toString(), content:xrtmlMessage});
```

Comment: my god, you did it. Works perfectly! Thanks